# Unable to change column width in a listview after creating it

Tags: c++, listview, winapi

I need to change column width using win32 api after adding some items to list view because width of vertical scroll bar causes horizontal scroll bar be displayed and i want to remove it.

But `ListView_SetColumnWidth()` does not change width of the column.

```
//Column
int CreateColumn(HWND hwndLV, int iCol, char* Text, int iBreite)
{

LVCOLUMN lvc;

lvc.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_TEXT ;
lvc.fmt=LVCFMT_LEFT;
lvc.cx = iBreite;
lvc.pszText =(LPWSTR)Text;  
lvc.iSubItem = iCol;

return ListView_InsertColumn(hwndLV, iCol, &lvc);
}

//item
int CreateItem(HWND hwndList, char*  Text)
{ 
 LVITEM lvi = {0};

 lvi.mask = LVIF_TEXT | LVCFMT_LEFT;
 lvi.pszText = (LPWSTR)Text;

 return ListView_InsertItem(hwndList, &lvi);
} 

 //Some code ...
 hwndList = CreateWindow(WC_LISTVIEW , L"" ,  WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | LVS_REPORT | WS_BORDER  | WS_VSCROLL , 10 , 10 ,300 , 200, hwnd, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0); 

 SendMessage(hwndList,LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE,LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT,LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT); 
 GetClientRect(hwndList , &rect);
 CreateColumn(hwndList , 0 , (char*)L"HEADER" , rect.right );

//Some other codes for adding items here

 ListView_SetColumnWidth(hwndList, 0,200); //Does not change the width
```

How can i change width of the column?

Comment: Why are you typecasting Unicode `const wchar_t[]` strings to `char*` just to cast them back to `wchar_t*` in the API? Get rid of the `char ` typecasts altogether. Use `const wchar_t*` for your `Text` parameters, and `const_cast<wchar*>(Text)` when assigning `Text` to `pszText`

Comment: ListView_SetColumnWidth works just fine for me. Post more code. How are you creating the ListView?

Comment: @Anders I added...I cant really figure out why that doesnt work...Im about to get mad

Comment: Your string code is still strange, remove all `(char*)` and `(LPWSTR)` casts! Only use `const_cast<LPTSTR>(xyz)`.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you should change your two 'Create' functions as follows (the second one is a lot different from your code):

```
//Column
int CreateColumn(HWND hwndLV, int iCol, const wchar_t* Text, int iBreite)
{
    LVCOLUMN lvc;
    lvc.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_SUBITEM; // You set iSubItem
    lvc.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT;
    lvc.cx = iBreite;
    lvc.pszText = const_cast<wchar_t*>(Text);
    lvc.iSubItem = iCol;
    return ListView_InsertColumn(hwndLV, iCol, &lvc);
}

//item
int CreateItem(HWND hwndList, wchar_t* Text, int nItem) // Must have an item ID!
{
    LVITEM lvi; // Don't set to { 0, } as you immediately overwrite first item ...
    lvi.mask = LVIF_TEXT; // LVCFMT_LEFT is just plain wrong, here!
    lvi.pszText = Text;
    lvi.iItem = nItem;    // Must set this value;
    lvi.iSubItem = 0;
    return ListView_InsertItem(hwndList, &lvi);
}
```

You don't show us the code where you add items, but you'll need to give each of these call an incrementing `nItem` value. Otherwise, your items will be shown in reversed order!

I'm also assuming you pass a non-const (i.e. not a string literal) to `CreateItem`. If not, then change it so it is similar to `CreateColumn` in the way it handles `Text`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Zahra19977 But, as **Anders** said in his comment, I tried using your code ***as you posted it***, and the `ListView_SetColumnWidth()` works for me, also.

Comment: So, what do you have in place of `//Some other codes for adding items here` ??